# QAF - Perfecto : Session aborted after 5 minutes due to user inactivity. Perfecto dashboard shows RemoteWebDriver

Tags: qaf, perfecto

When we are running parallel test from TestNG on perfecto cloud for browsers, once the execution is over, we are seeing that many failures are reported on perfecto dashboard with RemoteWebDriver name on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you observed additional results only with data driven test? I observed additional report entry for each testcase with `RemoteWebDriver` name and status `unknown` in addition to report with actual testcase name and `pass`/`fail` result. That looks like bug in perfecto report. In either case you should open perfecto support ticket.

Comment: Thanks ! We have opened up the ticket and following it up.